# Need help getting my Apex Code coverage to 75%

Tags: salesforce

I'm currently getting 58% code coverage and I need it to be 75% in order to deploy to production.

Below is my Apex Test Class and at the very bottom is my Apex class.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class VaultVFTEST {

/*This is a test class for the class VaultVF which is a Visusalforce controller for
the page vault */

static testMethod void VaultVFTEST() {

    //Create opp, hardcode the Deal_Registration_Id__c field with 'x111111111' and insert opp
    //Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='test opp', StageName='stage', Probability = 95, CloseDate=system.today());
    //insert opp;

    //Create a vault record that will be submitted
    Vault__c vlt = new Vault__c(
        Scenario__c = 'BIG-IP front ending Firewalls',
        isValidDealReg__c = true,
        Status__c = 'Application Received',
        Load_Balancer_is_a_Firewall__c = 'Yes',
        Providing_DDos_Connection__c = 'Firewalls',
        Providing_DDos_protection_except_ASM__c = 'Yes',
        No_Traffic_Traverse__c = 'Yes',
        Firewall_Vendor_Name__c = 'Firewall Vendor Company',
        First_Name__c = 'Test First Name',
        Last_Name__c = 'Test Last Name',
        Company_Name__c = 'Test Company Name',
        Phone__c = '(206) 946-3126',
        //Email__c = 'test@email.com',
        Country__c = 'United States',
        Additional_Info__c = 'Test Additional Info'
        //Related_Opp__c = opp.Id        
    );

    //Setup page for standard controller
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(vlt);

    Test.startTest();  
    VaultVF controller = new VaultVF(sc);
    Test.stopTest();

    //Assert has errors method returns true
    system.assert(controller.getHasErrors() == false);

    //Build the captcha value
    controller.getChar1();
    controller.getChar2();
    controller.getChar3();
    controller.getChar4();
    controller.getChar5();
    controller.getChar6();

    //Set captcha input value
    controller.captchaInput = '';

    //Attempted to submit form
    controller.save();

    //Assert terms checkbox was not selected
    system.assert(controller.errorMsgs[0].startsWith('You must'));

    //Assert verification code was incorrect
    system.assert(controller.errorMsgs[1].startsWith('Verification code'));

    //'Check' the box, set captcha value and then save
    controller.scenario1 = true;
    controller.captchaInput = controller.correctAnswer();
    controller.save();

}
}
```

Below is my Apex Class

```
public with sharing class VaultVF {

public Vault__c vault {get; set;}
public List<String> errorMsgs {get; set;}
public String saveResult {get; set;}
public String dealReg {get; set;}
public String oppId {get; set;}
public String email {get; set;}
public Boolean scenario1{get; set;}
public Boolean scenario2{get; set;}
public Boolean scenario3{get; set;}

// Generates country dropdown from country settings 

public List<SelectOption> getCountriesSelectList() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '-- Select One --'));        

    // Find all the countries in the custom setting 

    Map<String, Country__c> countries = Country__c.getAll();

    // Sort them by name 

    List<String> countryNames = new List<String>();
    countryNames.addAll(countries.keySet());
    countryNames.sort();

    // Create the Select Options. 

    for (String countryName : countryNames) {
        Country__c country = countries.get(countryName);
        options.add(new SelectOption(country.Two_Letter_Code__c, country.Name));
    }
    return options;
}

//Constructor, set defaults
public VaultVF(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    vault = (vault__c)controller.getRecord();

    //Populate list of random characters for CAPTCHA verification
    characters = new List<String>{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',
        'i','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w',
        'x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
    };

    errorMsgs = new List<String>();

}

//Determine if page has error so errors message can be displayed
public boolean getHasErrors(){
    if(ApexPages.hasMessages() == true){
        if(errorMsgs == null){
            errorMsgs = new List<String>();             
        }

        //Loop through errors and add to a list
        for(ApexPages.Message m : ApexPages.getMessages()){
            if(m.getSummary().startsWith('Uh oh.')){
                errorMsgs.add(String.valueOf(m.getSummary()));
            }
        }
    }
    return ApexPages.hasMessages();     
}

public void save(){
    errorMsgs = new List<String>();

    //Make sure captcha was correct
    if(validateCAPTCHA() == false){
        errorMsgs.add('Verification code was incorrect.');
        captchaInput = '';
    }

    //Make sure the Scenario is selected        
    if(scenario1 == true){
        vault.Scenario__c = 'BIG-IP as a Firewall';
    }else if(scenario2 == true){
        vault.Scenario__c = 'BIG-IP providing firewall service in conjunction with other vendors';
    }else if(scenario3 == true){
        vault.Scenario__c = 'BIG-IP front ending Firewalls';
        if(vault.Load_Balancer_is_a_Firewall__c == null){
           errorMsgs.add('Please specify if the load balancer is a firewall.');
        }
        if(vault.Providing_DDos_Connection__c == null){
           errorMsgs.add('Please specify if this is providing DDos connection level protection for firewalls or both.');
        }
        if(vault.Providing_DDos_protection_except_ASM__c == null){
           errorMsgs.add('Please specify if we are providing DDos protection (except ASM).');
        }
        if(vault.No_Traffic_Traverse__c == null){
           errorMsgs.add('Please specify if there is Traffic that does not traverse the Firewalls.');
        }
        if(vault.Firewall_Vendor_Name__c == null){
           errorMsgs.add('Please specify a Firewall Vendor.');
        }
    } else {
        errorMsgs.add('Please select one of three Scenarios that is similar to your setup');
    }     

    //-----Need to make sure deal registration number on opportuntiy is valid.-----

    //Set some sort of is valid deal reg flag to false. We will assume the deal reg Id entered is invalid until we determine it is valid
    vault.isValidDealReg__c = false;

    //Query Account Id, and Deal_Registration_Id__c from the opportunity object where the deal registration Id equals the value entered in the form
    List<Opportunity> opps = [select Id, Deal_Registration_ID__c from Opportunity where Deal_Registration_ID__c = :vault.Deal_Registration__c];

    //check to see if  registration id on the opp match the entered value    
    if(opps.size() > 0 && opps[0].Deal_Registration_ID__c == vault.Deal_Registration__c){

    //If they do match set the valid deal reg Id flat to true
        vault.isValidDealReg__c = true;
        vault.Related_Opp__c = opps[0].Id;

    //If they don't match then query all contacts on the account related to the opportunity
    }

    //If is valid deal reg flag is false add a message to the errorMSgs list indicated the entered
    //deal registration is not valid with details on who they should contact
    if(errorMsgs.size()>0){
        //stop here
    } else if(vault.isValidDealReg__c == false){
        errorMsgs.add('Deal Registration # was incorrect. Please contact your representative.');
    } else {
        try{
            vault.Status__c = 'Application Received';
            insert vault;
            saveResult = 'success';

        }catch(exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Uh oh. Something didn\'t work quite right. Please contact partners@f5.com for assistance. \n\n' + e.getMessage()));                
            saveResult = 'fail';
        }
    }

}

//------------------------Code for CAPTCHA verification----------------------------
public String captchaInput {get; set;}
List<String> characters;
String char1; 
String char3; 
String char5;

//This methods simply returns a random number between 0 and the size of the character list
public Integer randomNumber(){
    Integer random = Math.Round(Math.Random() * characters.Size());
    if(random == characters.size()){
        random--;
    }
    return random;
}

/*Here we have 6 get methods that return 6 random characters to the page.
For chars 1,3, and 5 (the black characters) we are saving the the values so 
that we can compare them with the user's input */
public String getChar1(){
    char1 = characters[randomNumber()];
    return char1;
}
public String getChar2(){
    return characters[randomNumber()];
}
public String getChar3(){
    char3 = characters[randomNumber()];
    return char3;
}
public String getChar4(){
    return characters[randomNumber()];
}
public String getChar5(){
    char5 = characters[randomNumber()];
    return char5;
}
public String getChar6(){
    return characters[randomNumber()];
}

public String correctAnswer(){
    return char1 + char3 + char5;   
}

public Boolean validateCAPTCHA(){
    if(captchaInput.length() == 3 && captchaInput.subString(0,1) == char1 && captchaInput.subString(1,2) == char3 && captchaInput.subString(2,3) == char5){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to 70% :)

Below is my updated Apex Test Class

```
@isTest
private class VaultVFTEST {

/*This is a test class for the class VaultVF which is a Visusalforce controller for
the page vault */

static testMethod void VaultVFTEST() {

    //Create a vault record that will be submitted
    Vault__c vlt = new Vault__c(
        Scenario__c = 'BIG-IP front ending Firewalls',
        isValidDealReg__c = false,
        Status__c = 'Application Received',
        First_Name__c = 'Test First Name',
        Last_Name__c = 'Test Last Name',
        Company_Name__c = 'Test Company Name',
        Phone__c = '(206) 946-3126',
        Email__c = 'test@email.com',
        Country__c = 'United States',
        Additional_Info__c = 'Test Additional Info'       
    );

    //Setup page for standard controller
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(vlt);

    Test.startTest();  
    VaultVF controller = new VaultVF(sc);
    Test.stopTest();

    //Assert has errors method returns true
    system.assert(controller.getHasErrors() == false);

    //Build the captcha value
    controller.getChar1();
    controller.getChar2();
    controller.getChar3();
    controller.getChar4();
    controller.getChar5();
    controller.getChar6();

    //Set captcha input value
    controller.captchaInput = '';

    //Attempted to submit form
    controller.save();

    //Assert verification code was incorrect
    system.assert(controller.errorMsgs[0].startsWith('Verification code'));

    //'Check' the box, set captcha value and then save
    controller.scenario3 = true;
    controller.captchaInput = controller.correctAnswer();
    controller.save();

    Test.startTest();  
    insert vlt;
    Test.stopTest();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After running your apex test class have a look at the code coverage results. This will show you which lines aren't being executed.

One way to do this is:

*Your name* > Setup > App Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Find your class and click the link in the code coverage column.